# Listview with radiobutton from server

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, radio-button

I am using [this](http://flowovertop.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-listview-with-radio-button-only.html) tutorial.I have a listview with radio button.when i click listview values all radiobuttons changing checked.i want single selection mode and checked radio button list values when i click submit button.
this is my onpostexecute

```
  protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
            Log.d("Arraylist: ", "> " + AddressList);

            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                   if(!AddressList.isEmpty())
                   {
                final ListAdapter adapterlist = new SimpleAdapter(
                            PlaceEnquiryActivity.this, AddressList,
                            R.layout.addressscreenlist, new String[] { ADDRESS,
                                    CITY, STATE, COUNTRY }, new int[] {R.id.address,
                                    R.id.city, R.id.state, R.id.country});

                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapterlist);
```

this is listview onclick function in activity

```
  final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rb_Choice);
            if (!rb.isChecked()) //OFF->ON
            {
            for (HashMap<String, String> m:AddressList) //clean previous selected

                rb.setChecked(true);
            //lv.getAdapter().notifyDatasetChanged();
            }
            }        
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making mistake by
for (HashMap m:AddressList) //clean previous selected

```
            rb.setChecked(true);
        //lv.getAdapter().notifyDatasetChanged();
        }
```

use conditions for already checked and not checked.if not checked then make it checked.Don't use for loop for setchecked(true)